# How to accommodate spaces in a variable in a bash and iterate in directory tree in linux

Tags: bash, centos, iteration, space

I am writing a bash script to iterate in directory and sub-directories, check if a file opened by a process,
if yes move it to another location
if no skip it
My issue is that the Source folders have Spaces is their names such as "FTP SYNC LOCAL"
my script is able so far to iterate in the folders and subfolders and test if a file is opened by another process.

It only does this if the file name doesn't contain a SPACE in its name, if it does, nothing happened

```
print_folder_recurse() {
for i in "$1"/* ;do
    if [ -d "$i" ];then
        echo $i
        #lsof "$i" | grep Serv-U | wc -l
        print_folder_recurse "$i"
    elif [ -f "$i" ]; then
        echo $i
        flag=$(lsof "$i" | grep Serv-U | wc -l)
            if [ $flag == 0 ];then
       echo "Done"
            elif [ $flag != 0 ];then
               echo "Skip Next"
            fi
    fi
done
}


path=""
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    path=$1;
else
    direct="/Source/FTP Sync"
    echo $direct
    path="$direct"
fi

#echo "base path: $path"
print_folder_recurse $path
```

The problem is at the bottom of the code with the variable "direct". If I write it

```
direct="/Source"
echo $direct
path="$direct"
fi

#echo "base path: $path"
print_folder_recurse $path
```

The file execute.

I can prevent the issue by writing the folder Source/FTP_Sync  but I can do this since it will affect a major workflow.

Any help will be apprecaited

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426859/bash-script-ignoring-whitespaces-in-script-parameters/40428501#40428501) to the similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `print_folder_recurse` functions reads the `$path` variable as 2 seperate arguments because of the space in between the variable i.e  `$1 = /Source/Ftp` while `$2 = Sync`. The solution is to wrap the `$path` variable in double quote like this `print_folder_recurse "$path"`so that `print_folder_recurse` can read it as a single argument

Comment: The `echo` commands should also have their arguments double-quoted (e.g. `echo "$i"`), although it usually doesn't matter. Usually. In general, leaving variable references unquoted is asking for trouble; spaces in filenames is only one of the things that can go wrong without them.